# Set the value of select html element with multiple attribute programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**Context**

```html
<!--HTML-->
<select class="form-select mb-1" id="document-select" name="documents" multiple size="10">                                        
    <option class="document-option" value="1">20230308-seed-document-0</option>
    <option class="document-option" value="2">20230308-seed-document-1</option>
```

```js
// JS
const documentSelectEl = document.getElementById("document-select");
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    documentSelectEl.selectedIndex = -1;
    documentSelectEl.value = ["1", "2"];
    console.log(documentSelectEl.value); // Empty string
    documentSelectEl.value = "1,2";
    console.log(documentSelectEl.value); // Empty string
}
```

**Issue**

I am trying to set the value of a `select` html element before form submission. My intention is to reset all selected `option` elements (`documentSelectEl.selectedIndex = -1`) - essentially ignoring them - and set the value of the `select` element directly.

The reason I am trying to achieve this is that the list of `option` elements is paginated. In other words, the currently selected set of `option` elements does not correspond to the full selection of the user.

I would like to pass the full set of selected values, which is retrieved from `sessionStorage`, either as an array or as a comma-separated string.

Neither of these options seem to work. I should note that looking at the value of the `select` element in the debugger, I always see a single value despite the `multiple` attribute. The value seems to correspond to the last selected `option` element. Does it mean that the only way to set the value of a `select` element with `multiple` attribute programmatically is by setting the desired `option` elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const documentSelectEl = document.getElementById("document-select");
const selectedValues = ["1", "2"]; 

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    documentSelectEl.selectedIndex = -1; // Reset all selected options

    // Set selected options based on selectedValues
    const options = documentSelectEl.options;
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        const option = options[i];
        option.selected = selectedValues.includes(option.value);
    }

    console.log(documentSelectEl.value); // Array of selected values
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way for the moment:

```js
// JS
function setSelectedOptions(selectElement, values) {
    values.forEach(value => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = value;
        option.selected = true;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
    });
}
```

Still curious whether a more direct approach is possible.